# target specific version of safari (jquery or css)

Tags: jquery, safari

I have specific problem that is only visible in safari 5.0 and it seems unfixable. 5.1 works and 4.x versions work.

Is there ANY method to target that specific browser and just hide the item or not run the jquery that's causing this trouble?

Comment: list of user agent here: http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Safari/ then check using navigator.userAgent in javascript

Comment: So if I want to target every safari 5.0 browser on any platform how can I do that?

Comment: You should tell us which particular code doesn't work on Safari 5.0, could be better way using feature detection using $.support. Or using javascript userAgent, check returned string using indexOf for multiple substrings which are only specific to safari 5.0

Comment: I wish I'd know what the particular problem is. It's this css slider http://tympanus.net/Development/ParallaxContentSlider/
The previous slides just do not hide on safari 5.0 and content stacks up. I'd be just happy to hide that part since every other browser works just fine